# Sourcemaps with webpack css-loader

Tags: css, node.js, sass, webpack, css-loader

I am struggling to get sourcemaps working with css-loader.

Output in console:

[image]

What the documentation from css-loader says:

> SourceMaps
>
> To include SourceMaps set the sourceMap query param.
>
> require("css-loader?sourceMap!./file.css")

**My webpack.config**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/js/App.js',

  output: {
    path: './public',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ] : [],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']},
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap!./file.css" },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  }
}
```

**How i include the sass**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'
import '../scss/main.scss'

render(
  <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory}/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. Enable [source-maps](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) via webpack

   ```
   ...
   devtool: 'source-map'
   ...
   ```
2. You might want to enable source-maps for Sass-Files as well

   ```
   module: {
     loaders: [
       ...
       {
         test: /\.scss$/,
         loaders: [
           'style-loader',
           'css-loader?sourceMap',
           'sass-loader?sourceMap'
         ]
       }, {
         test: /\.css$/,
         loaders: [
           "style-loader",
           "css-loader?sourceMap"
         ]
       },
       ...
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Use [extract text plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to extract your css into a file.

   ```
   ...
   plugins: [
     ...
     new ExtractTextPlugin('file.css')
   ]
   ...
   ```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was away just when I needed to get this fixed :D. If I include the `css-loader?sourceMap` in the `sass` section i get the following error: `Refused to load the stylesheet 'blob:http%3A//localhost%3A4004/c220aee3-8b79-49f8-b487-022859dbef73' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".` I do wonder if I am using sass and the css module incorrectly

Comment: Ok the above error as that was due to meta data security I had set, taken from an example. Now I set your example put and I have it showing me that it is from the file `main.scss` but sourcemaps are still not working as it doesn't show the line number or file name correctly.

Comment: I am upvoting your answer because the `?sourcemap`  params on the scss loader was what is needed. @D

Comment: I'm just wondering, how to apply `devtool: 'eval'` for JS (for quicker dev debug)

and enable source maps for the ExtractTextPlugin (without devtool: 'source-map' it doesn't work).

Comment: Webpack 1.13 here. Doesn't work for me - no css file is extracted. I had to put `ExtractTextPlugin.extract()` inside the loader and as parameter pass these css and sass loaders in array form.

Answer (score 0):

There are some properties you need to set in your webpack config.

```
{
   output: {
      ...
   },

   debug: true, // switches loaders into debug mode
   devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map', // or one of the other flavors, not entirely sure if this is required for css source maps
   ...
}
```

The webpack dev server doesn't have debug on by default. Instead of setting it in your config, you can also pass the -d or --debug flag to `webpack-dev-server` via the CLI.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't change my outcome. It still displays the <style>...</style> inside the inspector

Comment: You're right I overlooked something. Source maps were switched on by my postcss configuration.