# Source Maps not working with Webpack

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs, source-maps

I'm pretty new to webpack and having some trouble configuring it to produce the necessary source maps. In the devtools it says

> Source Map detected

but it shows the bundle and not the original code:

[image: screen shot 2016-06-20 at 18 04 05]

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    "./src/index.js"
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: '/',
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.scss', '.js', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['react-hot','babel']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["style", "css?sourceMap", "sass?sourceMap"]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: { hot: true },
  plugins: [ new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() ],
  inline: true,
  progress: true,
  colors: true
};
```

And here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev:test": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.test.config.js",
    "test:bundle": "./node_modules/.bin/tape test/bundle.js",
    "dev:serve": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config webpack.development.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "on-build-webpack": "^0.1.0",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "tape": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

I've tried multiple variations of the `devtool` option and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311222/sourcemaps-with-webpack-css-loader), [this](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/207) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296967/webpack-dev-server-doesnt-generate-source-maps) but no luck.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I can't get it to even say source map detected

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In `bundle.js` you will see original transpiled webpack bundle - this is normal behaviour.

Open `webpack://` and you will see your project files.

[image]

Comment: Right, but why does Chrome keep pestering you that a Source Map was detected, if it shows it already?

Comment: There are currently issues with Chrome, if this answer does not solve the issue, then take a look here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3165

Comment: @Everettss Thanks for the answer. If I am seeing an error in console which shows the uglified trace, how can I find the original variable/function name? For example, I am seeing

`(index):27 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bolt due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e` 

My app is compiling and working without minification, but fails when I run webpack in production mode because of above error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Add the following in your webpack.config.js file:

```
devtool: "#inline-source-map",
```

You can find clear information about it from the webpack website: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Also please find attached screenshot of sourcemap part from the webpack website.

[image]

Comment: It should be `devtool: "inline-source-map",` in case of Webpack 5+

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have `--mode development` in your `npm` build script,

```
{
 "name": "test",
 "version": "1.0.1",
 "description": "",
 "scripts": {
 "build": "webpack",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
 },
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "webpack": "^4.19.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
 }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/web.js',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["babel-preset-env"]
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000,
        watchOptions: {
            index: 'index.html',
            open: true,
            poll: true,
            watchContentBase: true
        }
    },
    watch: true,
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 500,
        ignored: /node_modules/,
        poll: 3000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue I was facing was in my `nginx` configuration. My nginx configuration was throwing 404 for the source map files, because it couldn't identify the `.map` files where to look for. So added `.map` also in addition to `.js|.css` and it was fixed.

```
location ~* \.(?:css|js|map)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I had a special character "ß" in my html:

```
<textarea
   id="start_location"
   defaultValue="Gerwigstraße 22, 76131 Karlsruhe"
/>
```

Changed the default value to `"Gerwigstra&szlig;e 22, 76131 Karlsruhe"` and the source map is working again.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'source-map' is not working, you can try 'inline-source-map' instead:

```
devtool: 'inline-source-map',
```

Or if you still wana use 'source-map', you can try to add this line in your plugins:

```
  plugins: [
...
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
  test: new RegExp('\.[js|css|mjs].*')
})
```

],