# Webpack's devtool (source-map) option not working while debugging popup.html of a chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webpack, source-maps

I am building a chrome-extension using react, webpack and babel. Webpack bundles html and js files into a folder from where chrome-extension is unpacked.
In my webpack config file, I wanted to use the following option for debugging:

```
{
    devtool: "source-map"
}
```

**When a bundled file is opened in the browser:** The above settings allows me to debugg the original code (rather generated/ bundled code) of html/js files when files are inspected in chrome-developer-tools in browser as normal file (not as an extension files). Here, the purpose of using 'devtool' settings in webpack is achieved.

**After bundled files are unpacked as a chrome Extension:** But while trying to inspect files (say popup.html) of chrome-extension, console (in chrome-developer-tool) shows bundled files (not the original code). So, the 'devtool' configuration option is not working here.

Where am I going wrong? Is there any additional settings requried in webpack configuration file, so that 'devtool' option can be used while debugging files of a chrome-extension?

Comment: Not tried but will this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928165/source-maps-not-working-with-webpack help?

Comment: @HaibaraAi That doesn't solve the issue. The "webpack://" option (as suggested in your link) is missing in chrome-developer-tools options for chrome-extension files.