# use scalajs source maps in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scala.js

I have a scalajs file, generated by sbt fastOptJS.
Google Chrome says:

> Source Map detected. Associated files should be added to the file
>   tree. You can debug these resolved source files as regular JavaScript
>   files. Associated files are available via file tree or _P.

However, I only see the transcompiled code, instead of the source scalajs code. How to see the scalajs code in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and the part that confused me is that the wording leads to to look for where Chrome is hiding the .map files, except it won't show you those. Instead, it has already rendered the data from those sourcemaps as a folder containing readable sources.

I'm not sure how you'd predict what that folder's name would be, but if you check out [this SO question about the same Chrome issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928165/) (though it's about webpack vs Scala.js) you can see that all the readable sources were available in a top-level folder named "webpack", so for your project I'd look for a folder with a name like "Scala.js".

Chrome could definitely be more helpful here, but for the price I can't complain.

Comment: I don't see any other top-level folder. :(